# animate method's property in jquery and its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please consider the following:
    `.animate({'marginLeft': '-='+width })`
It's part of a code that runs smoothly and fine,but what exactly does `{'marginLeft': '-='+width }` mean? 
i know that `a-=b` is the same as `a=a-b` ,but i don't seem to understand the above case,thanks in advance.

Comment: ["Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading `+=` or `-=` sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property."](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you set `width` dynamically, hence you don't write:

```
.animate({'marginLeft': '-=200px' })
```

You just concatenate the this string `-=` with the value of `width`, in order to have the same result, a string containing `-=value`.

The minus sign is associated with an animation towards to the left direction, while a positive sign is associated with an animation towards to the right direction.

In order to understand better the latter, I posted here an example from jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```js
$(function(){

    $( "#right" ).click(function() {
        $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
    });
 
    $( "#left" ).click(function(){
        $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
    });
  
});

</script>
```

```css
 div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #abc;
    left: 50px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="left">&laquo;</button>
<button id="right">&raquo;</button>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: yes but what i really meant is how to express `{'marginLeft': '-='+width }` in a simpler way. Is `{marginLeft: marginLeft-width}` the same thing as above?